# Handle two connection for multiple PC's (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ASP.NET MVC project.

In WebConfig file I have a connection to local db.

Here is code:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-SV2O11U;Initial Catalog=RIS_Main;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="RIS_MainEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-SV2O11U;initial catalog=RIS_Main;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But the problem in that I working on two pcs, work and home.

So it has a different name.And I need to change DataSource in `DefaultConnection`

Is there any variant to keep 2 pcs name in `connectionStrings`?

Comment: Is the database always on the same host as the application server? Then you can use `localhost` in your config file.

Comment: So I need to write `DataSource=localhost`? @rollstuhlfahrer

Comment: Yeah it works. Thank's @rollstuhlfahrer

Comment: It depends on what version of Visual Studio (and SQL Express) you have.
In vs 2017  Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;

Comment: Great, I have written an answer that shows another option. If it satisfies your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve it:

If your database server is on the same host as your application server, you can access the database via `localhost` host.

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=RIS_Main;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The other way is to have multiple transformations of the same config file (like you already have with Debug and Release).

[image: Add Config Transform]

Using this way, depending on your build configuration you can have multiple completely different connection strings. Visual Studio will decide during build which one to acutually use.

[Image Source](http://%5Ehttp://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/4100)